# is there a uniformly bounded property for $|f^{\epsilon}-f|$ ,where $f^{\epsilon}$ are the mollifiers?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

According to Lebesgue's differentiation theorem,
$$\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{1}{|B(x,r)|}\int_{B(x,r)}|f(y)-f(x)|dx=0$$
holds for a.e. $x\in \Omega$

Then for a fixed point $x$,
\begin{align}|f^{\epsilon}-f|&=|\int_{B(x,\epsilon)}\eta_{\epsilon}(x-y)[f(y)-f(x)]dy|\\
&\leq \frac{1}{\epsilon^n}\int_{B(x,\epsilon)}\eta(\frac{x-y}{\epsilon}|f(y)-f(x)|)dy\\
&\leq C\frac{1}{|B(x,\epsilon)|}\int_{B(x,\epsilon)}|f(y)-f(x)|dy\to0 \;as  \; \epsilon\to 0
\end{align}

i.e. $f^{\epsilon}$converges to $f$ a.e. in $\Omega$.

$\eta$ is the standard mollifier

$$
\eta(x)=\begin{cases}
C \exp(\frac{1}{|x|^2-1})\;\; if |x|<1\\
0\;\;if |x|\geq 1
\end{cases}
$$
the constant C is selected so that $\int_{R^n}\eta(x)dx=1$.
and for each $\epsilon>0$.
$$\eta_{\epsilon}(x)=\frac{1}{\epsilon ^n}\eta(\frac{x}{\epsilon})$$

f is locally integrable,
$$f^{\epsilon}=\int_{\Omega}\eta_{\epsilon}(x-y)f(y)dy$$
for $x\in \Omega_{\epsilon}$.

Now for some questions I'm working on, I want to use the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem, and for that, I need to show that$|f^{\epsilon}-f|$is a.e. uniformly bounded for small enough $\epsilon$ so that I can find a dominating function.